# How to make countdown function with hourly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to make countdown function , It is work unless hour time ! But I want to make 2 hours countdown time , I can't figure more ?

```
<div id="time"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var hour = 2 ;
var min = 30;
 var countdown = hour * min * 60 * 1000;
 //var countdown = hour * 3600 * min * 60 * 1000; also not working
    var timeload = setInterval(function () {
        countdown -= 1000;
        var hr   = Math.floor(countdown/(60 * 60 * 1000));
        var min = Math.floor(countdown / (60 * 1000));
        var sec = Math.floor((countdown - (min * 60 * 1000)) / 1000);  

        if (countdown <= 0) {
            alert("Timeout !");
            clearInterval(timeload);           
        }
         else {            
            $("#time").html("<font color='red'>Allowed Time </font>" + hr + " : " + min + " : " + sec);
        }
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

Actual Started Time
**Allowed Time 0 : 59 : 59**

Expected Start Time **Allowed Time 2 : 29 : 59**

Comment: There is a logical error here, you're not correctly converting these values. For example with the given input `2 * 30 * 60 * 1000` is equal to `60 * 60 * 1000`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this solution, you have an error on calculation time (`hr`, `min`, `sec`) it should modulus to maximum each value and also you wrong when convert `hour` and `min` to millisecond

```js
var hour = 2 ;
var min = 30;
var countdown = (hour * 60 * 60 * 1000) + (min * 60 * 1000);
var timeload = setInterval(function () {
  countdown -= 1000;
  var hr   = Math.floor( (countdown / (60 * 60 * 1000)) % 24 );
  var min = Math.floor( (countdown / (60 * 1000)) % 60 );
  var sec = Math.floor( (countdown / 1000) % 60 );  

  if (countdown <= 0) {
    alert("Timeout !");
    clearInterval(timeload);           
  }
  else {            
    $("#time").html("<font color='red'>Allowed Time </font>" + hr + " : " + min + " : " + sec);
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="time"></div>
```

Comment: Yes it worked ! Can you explain this working code @SpencerWieczorek as your own answer .! I m not seen about getting `hr , min ,sec` ?

Comment: what do you mean about ( not seen about getting `hr` , `min` ,`sec` ) ?

Comment: I mean ,not understand the code flow of getting that .

Comment: this code try to convert millisecond to hour, minute or second, i thing it's simple convert algorithm,  i found this tutorial for better explained https://www.sitepoint.com/build-javascript-countdown-timer-no-dependencies/

Answer (score 0):

I think your calculations may be wrong. You don't want to multiply the hours by the minutes, but rather add them up in some way.

```
// useful numbers for calculations into milliseconds
var _1sec = 60 * 1000, _1min = 60 * _1sec, _1hr = 60 * min;

// renamed `hour` to cHR (countdown hour) so I can keep things straight in my head
var total_ms = (cHr * _1hr) + (cMin * _1min);
```

The hours/minutes/seconds for display also needs reworking.

```
// Mod (%) takes the remainder after division. So countdown % _1hr takes whatever is left over that doesn't go into whole hours, etc.
hr = Math.floor(countdown / _1hr);
min = Math.floor((countdown % _1hr) / _1min);
sec = Math.floor((countdown % _1min) / _1sec);
```

Answer (score 0):

an example using diff between start and finish

```js
var hour = 2;
var min = 30;
var finish = new Date();
finish.setHours(finish.getHours() + hour);
finish.setHours(finish.getHours(), finish.getMinutes() + min)
var diff = finish.getTime() - new Date().getTime()
var timeload = setInterval(function() {
  diff -= 1000
  var s = Math.floor(diff / 1000);
  var m = Math.floor(s / 60);
  var h = Math.floor(m / 60);
  h %= 24;
  m %= 60;
  s %= 60;
  if (diff <= 0) {
    alert("FINISH!!");
    clearInterval(timeload);
  } else {
    $("#time").html("<font color='red'>Allowed Time </font>" + h + " : " + m + " : " + s);
  }
}, 1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="time"></div>
```